# Data Binding and UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, treeview

I need your opinion about UI and Databinding in WPF.

I had argue with my supervisor about UI & databinding. There is A class, it has ObservableCollection of B class, and B class also has ObservableCollection of C class. These classes are used while communicating with NI CAN and LIN device(it is not case).

On the other hand, in user interface there are bunches of TreeView and DataGrids. There are several instances of A class which is used to store data from devices and files, and they are binded to Treeview and Datagrids. But, he disagrees with this, and says to make separate other list of variables for TreeView and Datagrid to data binding. As he says UI data and other must be separate and I agree with it. But, in this case there are several lists of lists of lists and for example: copy from one list to other list when there is change on data takes much time and calculation ( -> UI element ). And other problems also.

I need your your opinion or other advice to come out better solution.

Thank you!!

Comment: Do the object models represent the exact same thing or separate things? Are you only meant to have one collection of the data, or do you expect to have more than one collection of the data? Its hard to tell what you're asking, perhaps some code will help. That said, its always best to do it your boss's way. Sure you can voice your opinion or disagreement, but if he still chooses to go with his way it's best to just do it.

Comment: There is no golden rule how the _view_ `TreeView` must be bound. Some use _"other list of variables"_; _code-behind_ or bind to a _view model_ (the *A* in your case).  You can chose to use MVVM or not.  It's up to you

Comment: @Roy,Thank you guys for your opinion. I think, sometimes we need to stand up for our ideas but practice says more things :)). So sometimes I need your opinion or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are a student and doing this work as part of your studies. Either way, there is something to learn here.

Why not implement both approaches and see how they differ, and which you prefer? As it stands your question does not provide enough information for anyone else to tell you, and there is no way to short cut this kind of learning in my experience.

Comment: Thank you for your attention in first!
For example, 
a) there is variable A which is used to store your data. And there is treeview, A is binded to treeview itemsources.
b) A variable to store data, B variable clone of A and B is used to bind for treeview itemsource. Which of them gives better performance ? :)